# Unable to access nested array in External Service response in Flow

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, external-services

I'm sending a request to the OpenAI API to return the sentiment based on the subject and description on a Case. I'm able to send the request successfully, and I get a 200 response, but I can't get to the value I want in the Flow. In the Flow debug I see the value I want, But when trying to update the record with the value I can't navigate to it from the Action response.

Here is the JSON used while setting up the External Service:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "defaultTitle",
    "description": "defaultDescription",
    "version": "0.1"
  },
  "servers": [{
    "url": "https://api.openai.com"
  }],
  "paths": {
    "/v1/completions": {
      "post": {
        "description": "Auto generated using Swagger Inspector",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "max_tokens": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "temperature": {
                    "type": "number"
                  },
                  "model": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "prompt": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "examples": {
                "0": {
                  "value": "{\n  \"model\": \"text-davinci-003\",\n  \"prompt\": \"Write a limmerick about APIs\",\n  \"max_tokens\": 250,\n  \"temperature\": 0.7\n}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Auto generated using Swagger Inspector",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "created": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "usage": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "completion_tokens": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "prompt_tokens": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "total_tokens": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "model": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "choices": {
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "finish_reason": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "index": {
                            "type": "integer"
                          },
                          "text": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "logprobs": {}
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "object": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "examples": {
                  "0": {
                    "value": "{\"id\":\"cmpl-71VjvXYUWDL8ixg1L7bUUzMATjnwI\",\"object\":\"text_completion\",\"created\":1680594691,\"model\":\"text-davinci-003\",\"choices\":[{\"text\":\"\\n\\nAn API is quite a find\\nIt helps us to be quite kind\\nWe can build apps with speed\\nAnd output data we need\\nNow let's all go and design!\",\"index\":0,\"logprobs\":null,\"finish_reason\":\"stop\"}],\"usage\":{\"prompt_tokens\":7,\"completion_tokens\":38,\"total_tokens\":45}}\n"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "servers": [{
          "url": "https://api.openai.com"
        }]
      },
      "servers": [{
        "url": "https://api.openai.com"
      }]
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "oauth2": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "flows": {
          "implicit": {
            "authorizationUrl": "http://yourauthurl.com",
            "scopes": {
              "scope_name": "Enter your scopes here"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the formatted response message I get in the Flow debug:

```
   {
    "z0object_set": true,
    "z0object": "text_completion",
    "usage_set": true,
    "usage": {
        "totalx5ftokens_set": true,
        "totalx5ftokens": 39,
        "promptx5ftokens_set": true,
        "promptx5ftokens": 34,
        "completionx5ftokens_set": true,
        "completionx5ftokens": 5
    },
    "model_set": true,
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "id_set": true,
    "id": "cmpl-71vm4FnSsJmgWsrwgDdCtagdtpUdn",
    "created_set": true,
    "created": 1680694768,
    "choices_set": true,
    "choices": [
        {
            "text_set": true,
            "text": "\n\nInquiry",
            "index_set": true,
            "index": 0,
            "finishx5freason_set": true,
            "finishx5freason": "stop"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm after is the "text" value in the "choices" array, but as per below screenshot I can't get to it in the Flow:

[image: Flow Update record element]

I've tried manually assigning variables in the Action response, but also not working.